# trying to change images when hovering over an icon in react

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am trying to change the src of an image while hovering over it with the mouse,
I don't know whether I should loop over an array or if there is a simpler way to perform what I am trying to do. Currently I have an image that is regular and one that is filled with a color. So there are two images.
they are both svg files and are located in my assets/images/ folder.

what is the best way to go about changing the state of the image when hovering over it ?

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom"
import { useState } from "react"

export default Navigation = () => {

    const icons = ["home", "movies", "tv-series", "bookmark"]
    const [ changeImage, setChangeImage] = useState([...icons])

    const onMouseHover = (event) => {
        setChangeImage(image => {
            image = event.target
            image = `/asseets/images/icon-nav-${}.svg`;
        })
    }

    const navIcons = icons.map(icon => (
        <Link>
            <img 
            src={`../../public/assets/images/icon-nav-${icon}.svg`}
            className="nav-icons home-icons"
            onMouseOver={onMouseHover}
            alt="home"
        />
        </Link>
    ))
    
    return (
        <div className="navigation">
           {navIcons}
        </div>
    )
}
```

I have tried creating a function to map over the icons and hovering over in state.
but all of the icons change. I just want the one that is hovered over. I know it has to do with event.target.src. I was thinking of creating a regexpression because the full source path is http://localhost:5173. I have created some other state of whether the image is hovered being true or false.
but it changes the fill state of all images and not just one.

Comment: You can do this in css instead of computing in javascript.

Comment: BTW your `onMouseHover()` function doesn’t actually do anything.

Comment: What will be the images on `onHover` and `onLeave`?

Comment: I am unable to perform this action because  css doesn't allow to change the fill color of the svg file. there are two svg images one that is filled and one that is not filled. I want the function onMouseHover to change the image  while hovering over it. Yes I do know the function does not work because I  am trying to figure out how it will work. Thank you for any help and assistance. I already tried this in css.

Comment: can I please get assistance with this issue ?